# Hive : Checking if a string from table 1 is present in a list of strings from table 2 while joining two tables

Tags: sql, string, list, join, hive

I am trying to join on whether a string(a column from table 1) is present in list of strings(a column from table 2) in Hive QL. Can anyone please help me with the syntax.

```
SELECT
A.id
FROM tab1 A
inner join tab2 B
ON (
 (array_contains(B.purchase_items, A.item_id) = true )
)
```

Above SQL does not work.

Answer (score -1):

First, unless Hive QL is backwards, your query is wrong upfront:

```
SELECT A.ID FROM A tab1
```

will return nothing because you've declared table "A" as "tab1". Either reverse the Alias or correct the table alias reference: (I assume tab1 is the table name, so go with option 1)

```
SELECT A.ID from tab1 A
 --OR
SELECT tab1.id from A tab1
```

Second, joins do not work based on conditional criteria, they ARE the conditional criteria. Sort of...

For example:

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM tab1 A
INNER JOIN tab2 B
ON A.item_id = B.purchase_item
```

is almost like doing a simple cross join with a WHERE condition:

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM tab1 A, tab2 B --better to use it straight as "FROM tab1 A cross join tab2 B"
WHERE a.item_id = b.purchase_item
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LEFT SEMI JOIN`, which would retrieve rows from left side table with columns matched from right side table.

```
SELECT A.id FROM tab1 A 
LEFT SEMI JOIN tab2 B 
ON A.col1 = B.col1 AND <any-other-join-cond>;
```

**Note that the SELECT and WHERE clauses can’t reference columns from the right hand table.**